# Should xsrf be a synonym for csrf

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should *xsrf* be a synonym for [csrf](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csrf)?

[OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSRF) treats it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.

CSRF is the standard, most widely used name.  Once upon a time, people used to sometimes use XSRF as an alternate name for the attack, but these days I don't see anyone using the name "XSRF" any longer.  And, we don't currently have any questions that are tagged XSRF.

So, my suggestion would be: use [csrf](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csrf) as the tag for these questions.  Don't introduce a synonym for XSRF; there doesn't seem to be any need for it.  Don't introduce a tag for XSRF.  If anyone happens to tag their question with XSRF (which hasn't happened yet to date, as far as I can tell), edit the question to replace XSRF with CSRF.

Comment: I agree with you, except I think that once someone *does* try to use `xsrf`, it then warrants a synonym.

Comment: Sounds good, @Polynomial!

Comment: Agreed. Don't add unnecessary tags if there are no questions tagged that way.

Comment: We should probably see about banning this tag, then.

Comment: XSRF is used in Tangled Web by Michal Zalewski. Also: [xsrf](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alcamtuf.blogspot.com+xsrf), [csrf](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alcamtuf.blogspot.com+csrf)